# OpenFileDialog with many extensions

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I need to have an open file dialog for 1000 file types (*.000 - *.999).
But adding it to the filter, the dialog gets really slow on choosing file types. Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

```
string text; 
for (int i = 0; i <= 999; i++)
{
    text.Append("*." + i.ToString("000") + "; ");
}

string textWithoutLastSemicolumn = text.ToString().Substring(0, text.ToString().Length - 2);
dialog.Filter = "Files (" + textWithoutLastSemicolumn + ")|" + textWithoutLastSemicolumn;
```

Comment: do you have any network connection shortcuts?

Comment: May I ask why you would want to do that in the first place? o_O

Comment: I'll join @derape comment, what is the purpose of adding so many extensions to open file dialog? `*.*` is enough. If you are making those files, then you shouldn't be using *different* extensions in first place (you can vary file name instead). It's ok to add few extensions, but not 1000.

Comment: It could be a split zip archive, which uses that naming format (amongst others) to store files.

Comment: As @Saragis mentioned, These are a split zip archive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're stuck with those extensions, I can see 2 possible solutions. Either accept this rather fast, but not 100% correct solution:

```
ofd.Filter = "Supported extensions | *.0??;*.1??;*.2??;*.3??;*.4??;*.5??;*.6??;*.7??;*.8??;*.9??";
```

This will accept all of your extensions, but also values such as *.0a1*, *.99y*, and so on. If you know those file extensions will not be a problem in your situation, this might be a good alternative.

A different solution might be to make your own implementation of the OpenFileDialog with support for regular expressions as a filter. This would be the best solution performance and security-wise, but I don't know how hard it'll be.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, using the "??" is sufficient in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried running the `OpenFileDialog` and it seems to run fast in my case:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i <= 999; i++)
{
    sb.Append("*.");
    sb.Append(i.ToString("000"));
    sb.Append("|");
}
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
string text = sb.ToString();

OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Filter = "Files (" + text + ")|" + text;
ofd.ShowDialog(this);
```

I have used `StringBuilder` to build the filter. And then convert it to string and passed it `.Filter` property.

Just to make sure here is a code that makes 1000-entries in the file types listbox:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i <= 999; i++)
{
    sb.Append("*.");
    sb.Append(i.ToString("000"));
    sb.Append("|");
}
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
string text = sb.ToString();

OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Filter = text;
ofd.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: Even with a `StringBuilder`, this code takes 20 seconds here.

Comment: Also, your code has a different behavior that OP's code has.

Comment: I modified the for-loop to build the filter with the pipe symbol (without the 'Test' word), in my case it is running quick in my machine. I wonder what is the difference.

Comment: OP's code produces a single entry. Your produces 1000 entries.

Comment: Still broken. Takes 25 seconds here. What does it do on your machine?

Comment: That's right, thanks for the correction. Loading was fast until the dropdown list is clicked, it becomes slower. But loading the dialog and building the filter doesnt take much time.

Comment: Unfortunately did not solve the issue when clicking on the dropdown list.

Answer (score -2):

You can add the following line.

```
dialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false;
```

This property of the `OpenFileDialog` will set whether the dialog should upgrade it's behavior and appearance when running on vista or above. By setting it to `false` we are making the UI rendering simpler which makes the dialog faster.

This the code I tried:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i <= 999; i++)
{
    text.Append("*." + i.ToString("000") + "; ");
}

string textWithoutLastSemicolumn = text.ToString().Substring(0,    text.ToString().Length - 2);
dialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false;
dialog.Filter = "Files (" + textWithoutLastSemicolumn + ")|" + textWithoutLastSemicolumn;
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

I added thsi to Load event of an empty Windows Form

Comment: May be you should include what that actually does and why this fixes the problem

Comment: No, it doesn't make it any faster. Actually tested it and it doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Should I post the code which I tried? It works for me

Comment: Go ahead. Why not give it a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately did not solve the issue when clicking on the dropdown list.